# Using java code in ipad application

Tags: ios, ipad, jar

I have .jar file containing java code (Business Layer) of an android application.Is there anyway i can use the same .jar file for developing corresponding iPad application in xcode?

Answer (score 1):

Since ipad applications are built using objective c,you must convert your java code in jar file to objective c.Use the tools like j2objc

http://code.google.com/p/j2objc/

Also refer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185334/is-there-a-good-java-to-objective-c-converter

Comment: Thanks,but i found issues with j2objc outcome code. Is there any other possible way for the same?